# Whats the best way to make a nested object of variable keys and depth?

Tags: javascript, json, loops

Whats the best way to make a nested object of variable keys and depth?

For example I'd like to take the array `["one", "two", "three"]` and create the following object:

```
{ 
  one: {
    key: value,
    two: {
      key: value2,
      three: {
        key: value3
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I was thinking I could use a for loop, but I'm not sure how to keep track of each of the levels.

Comment: How do you get the `value` and `value1` etc

Comment: `value` could be `i` of a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) to add a level of nesting in each loop.

```js
let arr = ["one", "two", "three"],
    initialValue = { key: arr.length - 1 }

const output = arr.reduceRight((acc, k, i) => 
  ({
      [k]: Object.assign({ key: i }, acc)
  })
, initialValue)

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thank you - also helped me understand a use case for reduceRight!

Answer (score 1):

> The [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method executes a provided function for each value of
>   the array (from left-to-right). The return value of the function is
>   stored in an accumulator (myObject).

```js
var aArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var myObject = {}, i = "";

aArray.reduce(function(oObject, sString) {
  oObject[sString] = { key: "value" + i };
  i++;
  return oObject[sString];
}, myObject);

console.log(myObject);
```